# How to auto-run import statements on starting Jupyter notebooks in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

When using Jupyter Notebooks I can usually modify

`C://Users/{username}/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py`

To add some code that I want to run every time I start a jupyter notebook (usually import statements).

However, this is not working when using VS Code notebooks.

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to write a `start.py` script at

`C://Users/{username}/.ipython/profile_default/startup/`

My `start.py` file looks something like:

```
import sys

CODE_PATH = 'D://Users/{username}/my-project/src'

sys.path.insert(0, CODE_PATH)

from projectlib.imports import *
import projectlib
```

And this works great.

Ps. I know "import *" is bad practice, but I do it consciously.